Rotating HTML content by 90 degrees for vertical printing without landscape class
I'm working on preparing a template for generating PDF files using CSS, where I have defined different paper sizes and orientations using @page and media queries. Here's a snippet of the CSS I'm using:
https://github.com/cognitom/paper-css/blob/master/examples/a4.html
Currently, I'm trying to figure out a way to rotate the content of the PDF by 90 degrees on a vertical page layout without using the landscape class. Is there a CSS-based solution to achieve this rotation for PDF generation? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


I need to avoid using form=landscape because the paper must be in portrait orientation as the device only supports that, and besides, there's an additional templating engine that adds various markers (and it is support only portrait pages). However, I could potentially start with a landscape paper and then somehow convert it to portrait with rotated elements.

I edited post by adding picture that describing input and output. I need to create page with horizontal text and convert it somehow to pdf file that will look in output section with presented layout. I use the landscape class to generate the pdf file, it is convenient, the content does not break my neck, but the expected output is vertical (including the content)

Try this:
CSS:
.rotate {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  width: 297mm;
  position: absolute;
  left: 210mm;
}

HTML:
  <section class="sheet padding-10mm rotate">


After converting it to pdf file i received empty pages. I am using gotenberg for it by api call.

Check your Gotenberg server logs and validate, this will be the initial problem of the empty pages.
